# Show text on ImageView UIL

Tags: android, text, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I want to set some Text on Image. How can I do this?
ImageView does not let me set the text and I want to use UIL but it take only ImageView as a parameter.

```
displayImage(String uri, ImageView imageView, DisplayImageOptions options, ImageLoadingListener listener)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy. I don't know what UIL do exactly. But this should help you

1. Create a custom view of your own.
2. Use a relative layout as its root layout container element.
3. Put Your Universal Image Loader Image first and TextView above to it
4. Create your own delegate/methods in your custom view that will pass ImageView to UIL
   and text to TextView.
5. Set visibility of element when images gets loaded. I hope UIL should have interfaces for
   that to notify client of image loading done state.

That should do what you want to achieve.

Hope it helps